# Extract a table using ajaxjquery response

Tags: html, jquery

I take a whole html code for page for extracting a table. Here is my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        alert("Hello");
        $.ajax(
        {
        url: '/Member/DownloadUrlData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {

        },
        success: function (data) {
           // $('#rData').load('data #container');

            alert(data);
            var theHtml = $.parseHTML(data).filter('#container>table:first').html();

           $("#rData").append(theHtml);

       },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    },
        complete: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
       }
   });

       <div id="rData">

      </div>
```

but i cant extract the table.the problem shown in error log is '#container>table:first' is not a function. how can i solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data` is the html markup, try

```
$(data).find('#container>table:first').html();
```

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Hello");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Member/DownloadUrlData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var html = $.parseHTML(data);
            var table = $(html).find('#container>table:first');

            $("#rData").append(table);

        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
        complete: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/taGQQ/2/)

Comment: there is no need to use it

Comment: still that problem remains

Comment: @user2598044 can you share the value of `data`?

Comment: @user2598044 there was a minor problem, I've updated the answer again

Comment: thank you very much i got the content. can i ask one more doubt, how can i get the images in that url

Comment: The problem is it is using a relative path for the images, you need to iterate through each image and update the source path

Comment: how can i change that path

Comment: how can change the image url

Answer (score 0):

replace `var theHtml = $.parseHTML(data).filter('#container>table:first').html();` 
by
   `var theHtml = $(data).find('#container>table:first').html();`